# Best way to iterate through all rows in a DB-table

Tags: python, mysql, database

I often write little Python scripts to iterate through all rows of a DB-table. 
For example sending all to all subscribers a email.

I do it like this

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = hst, user = usr, passwd = pw, db = db)
cursor = conn.cursor()
subscribers = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriber;")

for subscriber in subscribers:
 ...

conn.close()
```

I wonder if there is a better way to do this cause it is possible that my code loads thousands of rows into the memory.

I thought about that it could be done better with `LIMIT`.
Maybe something like that:

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriber LIMIT %d,%d;" % (actualLimit,steps)
```

Whats the best way to do it?
How would you do it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

unless you have BLOBs in there, thousands of rows shouldn't be a problem. Do you know that it is?

Also, why bring shame on yourself and your entire family by doing something like

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriber LIMIT %d,%d;" % (actualLimit,steps)
```

when the cursor will make the substitution for you in a manner that avoids SQL injection?

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriber LIMIT %i,%i;", (actualLimit,steps))
```

Comment: @pyfunc. I've written too much PHP in my life. I can't look at insecure code without cringing.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I didn't know that execute(...) is able to avoid SQL injection. However it is a script for local use.

Comment: "it is a script for local use." How many times has that been said?

Answer (score 18):

You don't have to modify the query, you can use the **fetchmany** method of cursors. Here is how I do it :

```
def fetchsome(cursor, some=1000):
    fetch = cursor.fetchmany
    while True:
        rows = fetch(some)
        if not rows: break
        for row in rows:
            yield row
```

This way you can "SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriber;" but you will only fetch **some** at a time.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, mysql will find all the rows that satisfy your query, but hold back sending them until you ask. The initial query of `SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriber` above would perform horribly for a table with billions of rows.  `LIMIT` means mysql searches for only the rows that satisfy your request and stops looking.  The docs on fetchmany weren't very helpful, so there might be some magic but I doubt it.

Comment: While not addressing your concern directly, here is the Python DB API interface that MySQLdb is implementing for the `fetchmany` method https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#fetchmany

Answer (score 8):

Most MySQL connectors based on libmysqlclient will buffer all the results in client memory by default for performance reasons (with the assumption you won't be reading large resultsets).

When you do need to read a large result in MySQLdb you can use a SSCursor to avoid buffering entire large resultsets.

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#using-and-extending

> SSCursor - 
>   A "server-side" cursor. Like Cursor
>   but uses CursorUseResultMixIn. Use
>   only if you are dealing with
>   potentially large result sets.

This does introduce complications that you must be careful of.  If you don't read all the results from the cursor, a second query will raise an ProgrammingError:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> import MySQLdb.cursors
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect(read_default_file='~/.my.cnf')
>>> curs = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)
>>> curs.execute('SELECT * FROM big_table')
18446744073709551615L
>>> curs.fetchone()
(1L, '2c57b425f0de896fcf5b2e2f28c93f66')
>>> curs.execute('SELECT NOW()')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 173, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

This means you have to always read everything from the cursor (and potentially multiple resultsets) before issuing another - MySQLdb won't do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all maybe you don't need Select * from...

maybe it's enough for you just to get some stuff like: "SELECT email from..."

that would decrease the amount of memory usage anyway:)

Comment: Great point - `SELECT *` Considered Harmful, or at least lazy programming.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have actual memory problems? When iterating over a cursor, results are fetched one at a time (your DB-API implementation might decide to prefetch results, but then it might offer a function to set the number of prefetched results).

Answer (score 0):

RS_1st = win32com.client.Dispatch(r’ADODB.Recordset’)
RS_1st.Open(“SELECT colA_, colB_, colC_ FROM tbl_subscriber “, Conn, CursorType = 3, LockType = 1)

for colA_, colB_, colC_ in numpy.transpose(RS_1st.GetRows()).tolist():

OR

for arrCol_ in numpy.transpose(RS_1st.GetRows()).tolist():

OR

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriber;")

for subscriber in cursor.fetchall():